# How to find .h,.c and .cc files under current directory in linux?

Tags: shell, find, pattern-matching

```
find . -name "*.[hc]|*.cc"
```

The above doesn't work,why?

**UPDATE**

How do I find these 3 kinds of files with a single pattern?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It doesn't work because `-name` expects a shell pattern. You can use `-regex` instead, or just assemble your pattern like so:

```
find . -name '*.c' -o -name '*.h' -o -name '*.cc'
```

**Edit**
To do this with a single pattern you'll want a regex:

```
find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(c|h|cc)'
```

You could do it with the default emacs regexes, I'm sure; I don't use them or know the main differences so I picked the one I know.

If you really want to use a single shellglob, you're out of luck: the only syntax for multiple strings is `{a,b}`, and this is not supported by `find`. But there's nothing wrong with the sort of command building/chaining in my first example. It's how `find` is intended to be used.

Comment: P.S. I know you're not using a regex there, but you're mixing syntaxes: the `|` is regex-only, just like the `*` is shell-pattern-only

Comment: Is it possible to do with a single shell pattern?

Comment: And it seems wrong,the conditions are `AND`ed,but I want `OR`

Comment: @kernel the `-o` means or. This will match any file that ends in `.c` OR `.h` OR `.cc`. are you saying that this command doesn't produce the output you expect?

Comment: Is it possible to do with a single **shell** pattern?

Comment: @kernel no. that was what i meant in the last paragraph

Comment: I think `{a,b}` is invalid in itself,as `ll {ucp.h}` fails when `ucp.h` DO exist.

Comment: @kernel let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/812/discussion-between-michael-lowman-and-kernel)

Comment: How to exclude directories from the result set of `find . -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(c|h|cc)'`?

Comment: @kernel you should try reading the `find` man page, there are many options. the one you want to add is `-type f`, or `! -type d`. The difference between posix-extended regexes and emacs regexes mostly have to do with which characters need to be escaped. both my regex and @Iain's will work. To learn about POSIX regexes (a standard) try `man 7 regex`.

Comment: Seems I can't use `-type f` together with `-regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(c|h|cc)'`

Comment: @kernel I don't know why not; `find . -type f -regextype posix-extended -regex '.*\.(c|h|cc)'` works fine for me. if you really have issues, you should post more information rather than simply saying it doesn't work. and this sort of back-and-forth in comments is discouraged; better to do so in chat and keep comments to things that directly answer your original question. if you have further questions, ask a new question.

Comment: Don't you get this warning? `find: warning: you have specified the -regextype option after a non-option argument -type, but options are not positional (-regextype affects tests specified before it as well as those specified after it).  Please specify options before other arguments.`

Comment: no, but that message is telling you to place options that don't affect matching (like `-regextype`) before matching commands (`-type` and `-regex`). Did you try modifying the command to meet those requirements? (That would be `find . -regextype posix-extended -type f -regex '.*\.(c|h|cc)'`). And no one's stopping you from using @Iain's. Seriously, I have no idea what possible reason you could have for not just using `-o`. It'll probably be faster; the POSIX regex engine isn't the best. And please, read the whole `find` manual. You may find it answers more of your questions than you think.

Answer (score 3):

If you really want to use a regex then

```
 find -regex "\(.*\.[hc]\|.*\.cc\)"
```

should do the trick but the more normal way to do this is to use -o as already demonstrated.

Comment: much better regex than mine ;) also i really should have just looked up emacs

Comment: @MichaelLowman: I was just thinking the same about your's but I can't upvote it again.

Comment: Is it possible to do with a single **shell** pattern?

Comment: @kernel: moon on a stick too ?

Comment: What's the difference between `-regextype posix-extended -regex` and your `-regex`?

Comment: @kernel: the [find manpage](http://linux.die.net/man/1/find) and [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) should help.